# echo a PDF-file from server

Tags: javascript, php, pdf

Is there a way to `echo` a PDF-file as response to a client-request which is written in javascript and let it be viewed by the user?

I'm generating the PDF with FPDF and I can save it to my server with the 
`$pdf->Output($filename, "F");`-function but I cannot access the directory where I stored the file from my client directly over an url.

That meaning I do **not want the user to be able to access the original file directly on my server** in any way.

So stuff like this won't work:

```
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=filename.pdf");
@readfile('path\to\filename.pdf');
```

or:

```
echo "<iframe src=\"file.pdf\" width=\"100%\" style=\"height:100%\"></iframe>";
```

Is there a possibility to translate a PDF-file to a String like with images to base64, echo it and then retranslate it with javascript back to a readable PDF?

Comment: Why you can't use `readfile`?

Comment: You wrote: *"then retranslate it with javascript"* - What if the user has JS disabled? You're back to *Square One* and have to resort to a serverside method. If you don't want them to figure out where that file is, then place it outside your public area. You also would need to change your `href`'s pointer (if you have one). All I see is an `<iframe>`.

Comment: You should be able to use the `readfile` method to send the PDF file from anywhere that a PHP script is allowed to save it to.That  includes folders outside the DocumentRoot which are therefore safe from prying eyes

Comment: FYI, even if you don't give the user a direct link to your PDF, they'll be able to save when it's being displayed. You have no control over what the PDF viewer allows the user to do nor can you stop the user from intercepting the traffic and saving it that way.

Answer (score 0):

If you use readfile + htaccess nobody can access your pdfs if you dont want to. Use header() and readfile() like in your example and block the access to the directory using htaccess or the httpd.ini ( if you use apache).